# Caught splinging at work

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, rhyme, language

> Én, to, tre, shabam,
>   go ahead an sprim that man!
>   Kvin, ses, sep, setresk,
>   saw him spling off on his desk!
>
> Nove, dez, onze, spling,
>   not setresk is such a thing!
>   Treize, quatorze, quinze, sprim,
>   I might have to shabam him!

What kind of trouble am I in?

Answer (score 88, accepted):

"*What kind of trouble am I in?*" You're... having a small stroke? :P But seriously:

> The odd lines are counting from 1 to 16 in *foreign languages* (except for 4 words in gibberish that also function as verbs), but these are easy enough to understand anyway. So if you substitute the nonsensical verbs with the numbers they stand for, you get:
>
>  go ahead an *sixteen* that man!
>  saw him *twelve* off on his desk!
>  not *eight* is such a thing!
>  I might have to *four* him!
>
>  ...Which could be deciphered if we use *the languages each original line was using*:
>
>  go ahead an *seize* that man! (16 in French)
>  saw him *doze* off on his desk! (12 in Portuguese)
>  not *ok* is such a thing! (8 in Esperanto)
>  I might have to *fire* him! (4 in Norwegian)
>
>  **So you were caught sleeping at your desk.** [Perhaps while counting sheep? ;)]

Comment: For an added bonus: Norwegian could also be Danish.